# How to move an element to the first position of a List in groovy

Tags: list, groovy

how do I reorder the list say:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

if user select banana, the list becomes

```
['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List pickToFirst(List list, int n) {
    return list[n,0..n-1,n+1..list.size()-1]
}
```

In your case,

```
    def list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
    def newList = pickToFirst(list, 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with the last element of the list (i.e. when `n == list.size() - 1`). You can try with `list[n, 0..n-1] + list[n+1..<list.size()]`, which, although less elegant, will give the right answer in those cases, as [`List#getAt(EmptyRange)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28groovy.lang.EmptyRange%29) will always yield an empty list.

Comment: Thanks. I omitted validity check all together, like if(n>0), list not empty, and certainly the issue you raised.

Comment: It is strange that `list[n, 0..n-1 , n+1..<list.size()]` doesn't work while separating it in two subscript operations does: `list[n, 0..n-1] + list[n+1..<list.size()]`. I think it's a Groovy issue, so i opened [a ticket](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5865) in their Jira :)

Comment: `list[n, 0..n-1] + list[n+1..<list.size()]` works fine for me. You also need to check if n==0  or n==1 in your caller function. Both cases causes duplication.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do it:

```
def list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
// get a reference to the selection (banana)
def pick = list.find { it == 'banana' }
// remove selection from the the list
def newList = list.minus(pick)
// add selection back at the beginning
newList.add(0, pick)
```

Answer (score 5):

Split into two lists and recombine - easily generalized for non-String lists:

```
List<String> moveToStart(List<String> original, String input) {
  original.split {it.equals(input)}.flatten()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering from the future year of 2022 since I had to look it up; using + and -.

```
arr = ["lol", "rofl", "omg"]
selected = "omg"
println([selected] + (arr - selected))
```